# postgresql: Is it possible to install postgresql 11 in Window 10 pro OS?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql for the first time.

I migrated my application from H2 db to Postgresql 10 db last week. 
I observed that "Stored Procedures" cannot be created in Postgresql 10 and therefore I need to install Postgresql 11.

The operating system used for development is Windows 10 Pro. In the Postgresql documentation it is pointed that for Postgresql 11 the operating system should be windows 2012, 2014 etc.

I want to confirm that Postgresql 11 can still run on Windows 10 pro, before deciding to migrate my windows operating system to Windows 2012 from Windows 10 pro, so that I save time.

Question: Is it possible to install and run Postgresql 11 on Windows 10 pro operating system?

Comment: Why do you need Stored Procedures? Can you not use Functions instead?

Comment: Yes it's possible to install Postgres 11 (or 12) on Windows 10

Comment: @JonathanWillcock stored procedures have a different transaction model resulting in different locking patterns, some things cannot be done using functions. and many other sings cannot be done efficiently.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name
Thank you.
I could install and run Postgresql 11 in Windows 10 pro